# MS SQL - Find Stored Procedure (Dynamic) Related to Table in Database

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have stored procedures like this:

```
CREATE PROC spSample (@departmentId INT)
AS

DECLARE @q NVARCHAR(500)

SET @q = N'SELECT * FROM Employees WHERE 1=1'
IF @departmentId > 0
BEGIN
  SET @q = @q + ' AND DepartmentId = @departmentId'
END

EXECUTE sp_executesql @q, '@deparmentId INT', @departmentId
```

It is possible to find all related SPs like this one to the table "Employees"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For dynamic SQLs, the only way to me is to search the definition of the stored procedure, like the following

```
use [your db]
select * from sys.sql_modules
where definition like '%Employee%'

-- if you know the pattern, you may use more restrictive way like
select * from sys.sql_modules
where definition like '% from Employee%'
```

But I have to say this may not be accurate. For example, if 'select * from Employee' is commented out in your SP, it will still be reported using this method.

Hope this helps.

Comment: @Middleman, I once wrote a tip about similar topic at https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3496/how-to-find-a-specific-text-string-in-a-sql-server-stored-procedure-function-view-or-trigger/

Answer (score 1):

You want to check out: [Redgate - SQL Search](https://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-search/)

It is a free plugin for SSMS to search for text in the SQL Server.
It searches in all kind of different objects (Tables, Views, Stored Procs, Agent Jobs, ...) in a convenient way.

Comment: Thank you! but it seems that it only finds the normal SPs.